# Kendo grid filter open popup/container position

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In the kendo grid when I click on the filter icon then popup opens but the alignment is set based on the icon. In 1st screenshot default, the open popup/container position and 2nd screenshot check after the apply changes.

1. [image]
2. I need to set it like this in a grid.
   need to be set dynamically for all columns.
   [image]

if anyone know how to apply this changes pls provide solutions

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is wrong which you are using second one after user clicks the filter then how he can understand what the data is present in the grid Because the second Picture is overriding to not see the data

I Think this link will help you how you can adjust the filtering
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/basics/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific option to adjust the popup container of the Grid filter. This means that some custom CSS would to be applied to the following selector:

> .k-animation-container

Feel free to check the following example that demonstrates the desired position from your second screenshot:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zzzuc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts